# Handling specimen creation inconsistencies between AutoFixture and Moq

Tags: moq, autofixture

I am using AutoMoqCustomization in my test conventions.

Consider the code below.  Everything works great until I add a constructor to one of the concrete classes.  When I do, I get "could not find a parameterless constructor".  We know AutoFixture doesn't have an issue with the constructor because it delivered me the test object `one` which proved to be assignable from IThings... no failure there.  So it must be moq.

This makes some sense because I assume `builder` was generated by moq and passed into the `GetCommands` method.  So I think I can see that control has been passed from AutoFixture to moq at that point.

That takes care of the why, but what should I do about it?  Is there a way to instruct moq on how to deal with the `ThingOne` or is there a way to instruct AutoFixture to ignore moq for `IThingBuilders` and instead do something Fixtury?

```cs
public class TestClass
{
    public interface IThingBuilders
    {
        T1 Build<T1>() where T1 : IThings;
    }
    public interface IThings
    {
    }
    public class ThingOne : IThings
    {
        public ThingOne(string someparam)
        {
        }
    }
    public class ThingTwo : IThings
    {
    }
    public class SomeClass
    {
        public List<IThings> GetCommands(IThingBuilders builder)
        {
            var newlist = new List<IThings>();
            newlist.Add(builder.Build<ThingOne>());
            newlist.Add(builder.Build<ThingTwo>());
            return newlist;
        }
    }
    [Theory, BasicConventions]
    public void WhyCannotInstantiateProxyOfClass(ThingOne one, ThingTwo two, IThingBuilders builder, SomeClass sut)
    {
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IThings>(one);
        Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IThings>(two);

        var actual = sut.GetCommands(builder);

        Assert.Equal(1, actual.OfType<ThingOne>().Count());
        Assert.Equal(1, actual.OfType<ThingTwo>().Count());
    }
}
```

Comment: This [answer](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/159#issuecomment-23314376) might help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As there's no extensibility point in Moq that enables AutoFixture to hook in and supply a value of `ThingOne`, there's not a whole lot you can do.

However, you *can* use the `SetReturnsDefault<T>` method of Moq. Modifying the above test would then be like this:

```
[Theory, BasicConventions]
public void WhyCannotInstantiateProxyOfClass(
    ThingOne one, ThingTwo two, IThingBuilders builder, SomeClass sut)
{
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IThings>(one);
    Assert.IsAssignableFrom<IThings>(two);
    Mock.Get(builder).SetReturnsDefault(one); // Add this to make the test pass

    var actual = sut.GetCommands(builder);

    Assert.Equal(1, actual.OfType<ThingOne>().Count());
    Assert.Equal(1, actual.OfType<ThingTwo>().Count());
}
```

This is a bit easier than having to write a specific `Setup`/`Returns` pair, but not much. You could move that code to an AutoFixture Customization, but again, since this is a generic method on a a Mock instance, you'll explicitly need to call this for e.g. ThingOne in order to set the default for that return type. Not particularly flexible.