# Mocking a dependency with AutoFixture

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, autofixture, automoq

I've recently started using AutoFixture+AutoMoq and I'm trying to create an instance of `Func<IDbConnection>` (i.e., a connection factory).

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());
var connectionFactory = fixture.Create<Func<IDbConnection>>();
```

This seems to work rather well:

1. My system under test can call the delegate and it will get a mock of `IDbConnection`
2. On which I can then call `CreateCommand`, which will get me a mock of `IDbCommand`
3. On which I can then call `ExecuteReader`, which will get me a mock of `IDataReader`

I now want to perform additional setups on the mock of `IDataReader`, such as make it return `true` when `Read()` is called.

From what I've read, I should be using `Freeze` for this:

```
var dataReaderMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDataReader>>();

dataReaderMock.Setup(dr => dr.Read())
                      .Returns(true);
```

This doesn't seem to meet my expectations though. When I call `IDbCommand.ExecuteReader`, I'll get a different reader than the one I just froze/setup.

Here's an example:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization());

var dataReaderMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDataReader>>();
dataReaderMock.Setup(dr => dr.Read())
              .Returns(true);

//true - Create<IDataReader> retrieves the data reader I just mocked
Assert.AreSame(dataReaderMock.Object, fixture.Create<IDataReader>());

//false - IDbCommand returns a different instance of IDataReader
Assert.AreSame(dataReaderMock.Object, fixture.Create<IDbCommand>().ExecuteReader());
```

What am I doing wrong? How do I get other fixtures, such as `IDbCommand`, to use the mocked instance of `IDataReader`?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18540861/126014

Comment: You're basically seeing the implications of this: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/176

Comment: @MarkSeemann I see... Looking at the [`MockConfigurator` source](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoMoq/MockPostprocessor.cs), I can see the mock's default value is being set to `DefaultValue.Mock`, and that's why `ExecuteReader` gets be a brand new mock of `IDataReader`. I'll see if I can create my own configurator to setup every method to make the mock call back into the `fixture` and get its return instance from the container.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As of 3.20.0, you can use `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`. This will automatically configure all mocks so that their members' return values are generated by AutoFixture.

E.g., `IDbConnetion.CreateCommand` will be automatically configured to return an `IDbCommand` from the fixture, and `IDbCommand.ExecuteReader` will be automatically configured to return an `IDataReader` from the fixture.

All of these tests should pass now:

```
var fixture = new Fixture().Customize(new AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization());

var dataReaderMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IDataReader>>();
dataReaderMock.Setup(dr => dr.Read())
              .Returns(true);

//all pass
Assert.Same(dataReaderMock.Object, fixture.Create<IDataReader>());
Assert.Same(dataReaderMock.Object, fixture.Create<IDbCommand>().ExecuteReader());
Assert.Same(dataReaderMock.Object, fixture.Create<IDbConnection>().CreateCommand().ExecuteReader());
Assert.Same(dataReaderMock.Object, fixture.Create<Func<IDbConnection>>()().CreateCommand().ExecuteReader());
```

Comment: `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization` is now obsolete, `AutoMoqCustomization` is preferred.

Answer (score 4):

You have to `Freeze` the `Mock<IDbCommand>` as well – and setup the mock object (as a Stub) to return the existing `dataReaderMock.Object` instance.

If you add the following to the Arrange phase of you test, the test will pass:

```
var dbCommandStub = 
    fixture
        .Freeze<Mock<IDbCommand>>()
        .Setup(x => x.ExecuteReader())
        .Returns(dataReaderMock.Object);
```

Comment: Does that mean I would also have to freeze `IDbConnection` and set it up to return `dbCommandStub.Object`?

Comment: Yes, you would have to `Freeze` the `IDbConnection` similarly if you access the `DbCommand` object from there.

Answer (score 1):

While the solution from Nikos works I would not I do not recommend mocking ado.net.

In my opinion your tests will probably be hard to understand, maintain and will not give you the confidence your tests should give you.

I would consider testing your data layer by going all the way to the database even though it is slower.

I would recommend reading this article regarding best practices for mocking:
http://codebetter.com/jeremymiller/2006/01/10/best-and-worst-practices-for-mock-objects/

Don't mock others:
http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2012/04/01/tdd-best-practices-dont-mock-others/

I don't know your exact situation but anyways I wanted to share this.

Comment: Thanks for your response. However, if I do go all the way to the database, then I wouldn't be writing unit tests anymore, I'd be writing functional tests. And I do have a comprehensive suite of functional tests to give me the confidence I need.

Comment: Also, that post was written 8 years ago. It might have been hard to mock a database connection back then (hard enough to not seem worth it), but that's certainly not the case nowadays. Plus, when I'm done writing my plugin for AutoFixture, it'll be doable in no more than 2/3 lines of code.

Comment: This is a general advice which I have from many books and articles. Maybe some of them are old but I would not think they are outdated. Here is an newer article on mocking others:
http://aspiringcraftsman.com/2012/04/01/tdd-best-practices-dont-mock-others/

What do you gain from your tests?

Comment: I would only do integration and maybe acceptance tests for my infrastructure code. But people disagree about this. If you feel that the test are not a burden and you are gaining anything from them you should maybe disregard my advice.

Comment: That last link you posted makes a good point about assuming the behavior of third-party libraries. For that reason, I don't couple myself to NLog or ActiveMQ, for example. Instead, I use our own custom `ILogger` and `ISendAdapter` interfaces, and then provide test doubles for those. Regarding database connections though, since `IDbConnection` is not vendor-specific, and is a well understood interface, I feel like it's ok to provide test doubles for it. I don't have integration tests though, maybe I should... Thanks for your input.