# AutoFixture/AutoMoq + NUnit AutoData Frozen Object not Returned By AutoMoq Interface Method

Tags: nunit, autofixture, automoq

Using the AutoMoqCustomization i would have hoped my test would work but it fails.

this is the test:

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
public void Test1(
    [Frozen] MyObject myObject, 
    [Frozen] Mock<IRepo> stubMock, 
    MyClass sut, 
    int objectId)
{
    myObject.Id = objectId;
    MyObject result = sut.GetById(objectId);
    Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(myObject.Id));
}
```

i can get this to work if i add one line of code. But i would like not to have to do this because it should be inferred??

```
    stubMock.Setup(r => r.GetObject(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => myObject);
```

The MyClass has a constructor with the IRepo. This is working like a charm because if i use the line above in my test i have a passed test.

usually i write my test without the auto data it a lot more verbose:

```
[Test]
public void Test3()
{
    IFixture fixture = new Fixture();
    int objectId = fixture.Create<int>();
    var stubMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IRepo>>();

    stubMock.Setup(r => r.GetObject(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => fixture.Create<MyObject>());
    fixture.Freeze<MyObject>(customise => customise.With(d => d.Id, objectId));

    var sut = new MyClass(stubMock.Object);
    MyObject result = sut.GetById(objectId);
    Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(objectId));
}
```

So already my code is much cleaner but idd like that last cherry on top :) Any Idea's???

How to run:

Add Nuget packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="AutoFixture" version="3.19.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" version="3.19.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoFixture.NUnit2" version="3.19.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moq" version="3.1.416.3" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

Full Code:

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
    {
        public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
            : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization()))
        {
        }
    }

    [TestFixture]
    public class Class1
    {
        public interface IRepo
        {
            MyObject GetObject(int id);
        }

        public class MyObject
        {
            public int Id { get; set; }
        }

        public class MyClass
        {
            private readonly IRepo _test;

            public MyClass(IRepo test) { _test = test; }

            public MyObject GetById(int id) { return _test.GetObject(id); }
        }

        [Test, AutoMoqData]
        public void Test1(
            [Frozen] MyObject myObject, [Frozen] IRepo stubMock, MyClass sut, int objectId)
        {
            myObject.Id = objectId;

            // expecting this commented line to be automatic because of the Frozen attribute on myObject? 
            // Mock.Get(stubMock).Setup(r => r.GetObject(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => myObject);

            MyObject result = sut.GetById(objectId);

            Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(myObject.Id));
        }

        [Test, AutoMoqData]
        public void Test2(
            [Frozen] MyObject myObject, [Frozen] Mock<IRepo> stubMock, MyClass sut, int objectId)
        {
            myObject.Id = objectId;

            // expecting this commented line to be automatic because of the Frozen attribute on myObject? 
            // stubMock.Setup(r => r.GetObject(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => myObject);

            MyObject result = sut.GetById(objectId);

            Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(myObject.Id));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test3()
        {
            IFixture fixture = new Fixture();
            int objectId = fixture.Create<int>();
            var stubMock = fixture.Freeze<Mock<IRepo>>();

            stubMock.Setup(r => r.GetObject(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => fixture.Create<MyObject>());
            fixture.Freeze<MyObject>(customise => customise.With(d => d.Id, objectId));

            var sut = new MyClass(stubMock.Object);
            MyObject result = sut.GetById(objectId);
            Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(objectId));
        }

    }
```

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18540861/126014

Comment: You're basically seeing the implications of this: github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/176

Comment: @MarkSeemann ah tnx that opens up a possibility.  It will probably work with single return types. I'll test if it works on multiple. Is there a way of getting the fixture being used for the auto data?

Comment: You can just ask for it as a method argument...

Comment: @MarkSeemann Wow thanks! I didn't think about that. I'll look in to it tomorrow and add a working solution to this thread

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 3.20.0, you can use `AutoConfiguredMoqCustomization`. This will automatically configure all mocks so that their members' return values are generated by AutoFixture.

Virtual methods/properties/indexers will be setup to lazily generate their return values using AutoFixture. If the method has `out` parameters, those will be setup as well.

Public fields and sealed properties will have their values set eagerly.

This test should pass now:

```
[Test, AutoMoqData]
public void Test1(
    [Frozen] MyObject myObject,
    MyClass sut,
    int objectId)
{
    myObject.Id = objectId;
    MyObject result = sut.GetById(objectId);
    Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(myObject.Id));
}
```

Comment: Nice! I'll toss my solution than.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @MarkSeemann for some hints i am getting to a solution to this 'problem'.

## My thinking

I started out With the MockRelay class in the AutoFixture.AutoMoq nuget package. I created an overload MockRelayExtras and i add that to the AutoMoqCustomozation.

What this will do is reflect on the interface or abstract class and setup the mock accordingly

ex.

```
Mock.Get(TInterface.Instance)
    .Setup( i => i.Method( It.IsAny<TParamType>() ) )
    .Returns( () => fixture.Create<TMethodResult>() );
```

For now this will only work for Interfaces and Abstract classes ( without constructors )

Its a start. The code will need some cleaning up though. Furthermore i hope other people will like, enjoy and use this?

Happy coding!

## Full Code

this is a working solution with sort of basis test proving it works.

### app.config

( this fixes resharper en test runner )

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Moq" publicKeyToken="69f491c39445e920" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.2.1408.717" newVersion="4.2.1408.717" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="nunit.core.interfaces" publicKeyToken="96d09a1eb7f44a77" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.6.3.13283" newVersion="2.6.2.12296" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

### nuget packages:

```
<packages>
  <package id="AutoFixture" version="3.19.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoFixture.AutoMoq" version="3.19.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="AutoFixture.NUnit2" version="3.19.2" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="Moq" version="4.2.1408.0717" targetFramework="net45" />
  <package id="NUnit" version="2.6.3" targetFramework="net45" />
</packages>
```

### Attribute

```
public class AutoMoqDataAttribute : AutoDataAttribute
{
    public AutoMoqDataAttribute()
        : base(new Fixture().Customize(new AutoMoqCustomization(new MockRelayExtras())))
    {

    }
}
```

### Updated MockRelay class

```
public class MockRelayExtras : MockRelay, ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public new object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        object result = base.Create(request, context);

        var requestType = request as Type;
        if (requestType != null && result != null)
        {
            SetupMockWithInterface(requestType, result, context);
        }

        return result;
    }

    public static void SetupMockWithInterface(Type requestType, object result, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        typeof (MockRelayExtras).GetMethod("SetupMockWithInterfaceGeneric")
            .MakeGenericMethod(requestType).Invoke(null, new[] {result, context});
    }

    public static void SetupMockWithInterfaceGeneric<TType>(TType result, ISpecimenContext context)
        where TType : class
    {
        //Mock.Get(stubMock).Setup(r => r.GetObject(It.IsAny<int>())).Returns(() => myObject);
        Mock<TType> genericMock = Mock.Get(result);

        foreach (MethodInfo methodInfo in typeof (TType).GetMethods())
        {
            // ISetup<TType,TMethodResult> setup = genericMock.Setup<TType,TMethodResult>( methodInfo )
            object setup =
                typeof (MockRelayExtras).GetMethod("SetupAsGenericFunc")
                    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (TType), methodInfo.ReturnType)
                    .Invoke(null, new object[] {methodInfo, genericMock});

            // setup.Returns( () => context.Create<TResult>() )
            typeof (MockRelayExtras).GetMethod("SetupReturnsAsGenericFunc")
                .MakeGenericMethod(typeof (TType), methodInfo.ReturnType)
                .Invoke(null, new[] {setup, context});
        }
    }

    public static ISetup<TMock, TResult> SetupAsGenericFunc<TMock, TResult>(MethodInfo method, Mock<TMock> mock)
        where TMock : class
    {
        ParameterExpression input = Expression.Parameter(typeof (TMock));

        ParameterInfo[] parameters = method.GetParameters();

        Expression<Func<TMock, TResult>> setup = null;

        if (parameters.Length > 0)
        {
            IEnumerable<MethodCallExpression> properties =
                parameters.Select(
                    pi => Expression.Call(typeof (It), "IsAny", new[] {pi.ParameterType}, new Expression[0]));
            setup = Expression.Lambda<Func<TMock, TResult>>(
                Expression.Call(input, method, properties), input);
        }
        else
        {
            setup = Expression.Lambda<Func<TMock, TResult>>(
                Expression.Call(input, method), input);
        }


        return mock.Setup(setup);
    }

    public static void SetupReturnsAsGenericFunc<TMock, TResult>(ISetup<TMock, TResult> setup,
        ISpecimenContext context)
        where TMock : class
    {
        setup.Returns(() => context.Create<TResult>());
    }
}
```

### tests

```
[TestFixture]
public class MockRelayExtrasTests
{
    public class RelayTestClass
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
    }

    public class RandomInputData
        {
            public int Prop1 { get; set; }
            public string Prop2 { get; set; }
        }

    public interface ISingleResultNoInput
    {
        RelayTestClass SingleResultNoInput();
        IEnumerable<RelayTestClass> ListResultNoInput();
        RelayTestClass GetItemById(int id);
        RelayTestClass GetItemById(int id, string randomSearch);
        RelayTestClass GetItemBySearch(RandomInputData data);
    }

    [Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Create_AutoMockInterfaceIEnumerableResults_InterfaceIsSetupWithIEnumerable(
        [Frozen] RelayTestClass itemTemplate,
        [Frozen] ISingleResultNoInput sut,
        [Frozen] IFixture fixture
        )
    {
        List<RelayTestClass> result = sut.ListResultNoInput().ToList();
        Assert.That(result[0], Is.EqualTo(itemTemplate));
    }

    [Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Create_AutoMockInterfaceMethodsAutoMoqData_InterfaceIsSetup(
        [Frozen] RelayTestClass frozenItem, [Frozen] ISingleResultNoInput sut, int expectedId)
    {
        frozenItem.Id = expectedId;
        RelayTestClass result = sut.SingleResultNoInput();
        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(expectedId));
    }

    [Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Create_AutoMockInterfaceMethodParameter_InterfaceIsSetup(
        [Frozen] RelayTestClass frozenItem, [Frozen] ISingleResultNoInput sut, int id)
    {
        frozenItem.Id = id;
        RelayTestClass result = sut.GetItemById(id);
        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(id));
    }

    [Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Create_AutoMockInterfaceMethodsAutoMoqDataMultipleInput_InterfaceIsSetup(
        [Frozen] RelayTestClass frozenItem, [Frozen] ISingleResultNoInput sut, int id, string searchString)
    {
        frozenItem.Id = id;
        RelayTestClass result = sut.GetItemById(id, searchString);
        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(id));
    }

    [Test, AutoMoqData]
    public void Create_AutoMockInterfaceMethodsAutoMoqDataComplexInput_InterfaceIsSetup(
        [Frozen] RelayTestClass frozenItem, [Frozen] ISingleResultNoInput sut, RandomInputData input)
    {
        frozenItem.Id = input.Prop1;
        RelayTestClass result = sut.GetItemBySearch(input);
        Assert.That(result.Id, Is.EqualTo(input.Prop1));
    }
}
```

### auto generated addin by package

```
[NUnitAddin]
public class LocalAddin : Addin
{
}
```

Comment: I will be updating this code on github: https://github.com/MarkStruik/AutoFixture.AutoMoq.AutoSetup